# Calculate speed of light beam cast onto sphere surface

Tags: vectors, physics, surfaces, spheres

Given an object (B) moving at constant speed and direction directly above a sphere (S) casting a light (L) on the surface of the sphere, how do I calculate the surface speed of the light at any given point or time?

[See this figure for visualizing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY6SI.jpg)

If B is traveling at 3500 km/h and the diameter of the sphere is 14000 km, then the speed of the light beam above each point on the diameter line would be constant at 3500 km/h, but on the surface I would expect the speed to be very high on each side of the sphere, but close to 3500 km/h in the middle (top point of sphere). Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Hence $$x=R\cos \theta$$
$$\theta=\cos^{-1} (\frac{x}{R})$$
Now we can get,
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
Now using basic knowledge of circular motion,
$$v_{\text{surface}}=\color{red}{-}R\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$v_{\text{surface}}=\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}v_{object}$$

> We have the $\color{red}{\text{minus}}$ because $\omega$ is anticlockwise, which would give us $v$ in opposite direction of what we want.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an example of use? For example, if the radius is 7000 km and the speed of the object above the sphere is 3500 km/t, after 2000 km, what is the surface speed? Is this formula using the mid-point as starting point?

Comment: Sorry i forgot $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in the last line,

Comment: x is just the distance from the midpoint

Comment: You must specify for what $x$

Comment: If I use x = 0, r = 7000, v = 3500 then I get ((7000^2) / sqrt(7000^2 - 0^2)) * 3500 = 24500000, but I was expecting something like 3500. The number is always very high if I increase x, am I supposed to use a delta value or is there something else I'm missing? Sorry, I'm a programmer, but my math is very rusty :) Really appreciate your input!

Comment: @neonpokharkar There is an error in the derivative: $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\frac{dx}{dt}$ and then $$v_{\text{surface}}=\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}v_{\text{object}}=\frac{v_{\text{object}}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{R}\right)^2}}$$ So for $x=0$, $v_{\text{surface}}=v_{\text{object}}$.

Comment: Yes, as  surface is parallel to path of motion of object at $x=0$ , the speed of beam of light will be Same as speed of emmiter\object

Comment: And thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: That seems to work beautifully! Thanks guys!